# How to start a Parachain on Rococo Testnet

Tags: parachain, rococo

I would like have a step by step process to get block production started with a parachain on Rococo testnet.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you test locally:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-relay

When you're ready for testing on Rococo testnet, you can follow this guide:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/rococo-slot

Once a Parity team member with sudo has uploaded your wasm and genesis state to the Rococo relay chain via the [subport issue you filled out](https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/432), you will have a temporary slot and can then run your collator and start producing blocks.

Comment: In docs for Relay Chain Locally, we are having a rococo_local_relay_chain_spec.json,
when we are having a parathread upgraded to parachain, 
what is process of step by step i would like to know
eg:-  how to start a relay chain for my parachain?(how to configure .json file)

Comment: The commands are the same as in the tutorial, just make sure you use the Rococo chain spec: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/node/service/chain-specs/rococo.json and modify your parachain's chain spec for production. You can look at other parachain team's chain spec for examples.

Comment: Iam having a confusion on after getting a parachain approved by polkadot team
What should i exactly need to do "to start produce blocks, add pallets to my parachain"
How should i should set up the chain spec file on relaychain template?
Should we need to generate new trusted nodes for my parachain?
How should i able to see that blocks are generating on polkadot apps UI website?
Pls help me with relevant steps 
Thank You.